# Use C-n/C-p in VsVim to select completion candidate in intellisense popup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsvim

I would like to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> instead of <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrows to select the completion candidate. I tried to 
`:imap <C-n> <Down>`, but instead of selecting the next completion candidate, the cursor will go down to the next line.

Comment: You can use Ctrl-P / Ctrl-N to navigate the windows that VsVim brings up but not normal intellisense windows.  I filed the following bug to try and add that behavior https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1149

Comment: Here is the issue that tracks getting Alt key binding support https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/806

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using a vim key mapping, you can handle this with a Visual Studio keyboard shortcut (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard):

[image]

The `Edit.LineUp` and `Edit.LineDown` commands are what you're looking for. You can see in the image above that I am using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for `Edit.LineDown`, but you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> instead. I prefer using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key because pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> dims out the Intellisense list, while <kbd>Alt</kbd> does not. Just a matter of preference though.

I formerly had this same question, and [I received the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18744507/1309005).

Comment: Did you do anything else with your setup to get this to work? I have VsVim installed and when I'm in edit mode, hit ctrl+space to start Intellisense, when I hit alt+J (after setting up your shortcut), it closes intellisense the second I press alt. When I try it with ctrl+J, it inserts a newline. Is there some vsvim setting I need to change too?

Comment: Hmmm...I don't remember any other changes that I made to get this to work (but my memory does fail me!). I just tested and Alt+J navigates the Intellisense list while Ctrl+J just dims out the Intellisense list. I noticed you said Ctrl+J enters a newline, so I went into Tools > Options > VsVim > Keyboard and changed the option for Ctrl+J to "Handled by VsVim" (I usually have it set to "Handled by Visual Studio"). When I did, I then saw the behavior you are seeing with Ctrl+J entering a newline. Not sure what's causing the Alt key to dismiss the Intellisense list though.